# Swift 3 Decimal, NSDecimal and NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to use `NumberFormatter` with Swift 3 `Decimal`, but I'm confused as to how `Decimal` is really being implemented. The problem I'm having is that `Decimal` is a struct, so I have to bridge it to an `NSDecimalNumber` every time I want to use a formatter, which I'd like to avoid.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let decimal = Decimal(integerLiteral: 3)
let string = formatter.string(from: decimal as NSDecimalNumber)
```

Is the ideal workaround for this to implement my own extension that takes a `Decimal`?

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    open func string(from number: Decimal) -> String? {
        return string(from: number as NSDecimalNumber)
    }
}
```

More generally, every time I need to pass in an object type am I going to need to bridge `Decimal` or write more extensions?

**EDIT**

I guess I'm wondering more generally about `NSDecimal` `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` in Swift 3. It's not clear to me at all what's going on here. Should I be replacing `NSDecimalNumber` with `Decimal` for Swift 3? The docs write:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Decimal structure, which bridges to the NSDecimalNumber class. The Decimal value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation classes.

Which at first I thought meant that `Decimal` was the new `NSDecimalNumber` like `Error` is the new `NSError` - but now I'm not so sure. That also says 'Decimal value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber reference type` - is this really true? I can't seem to get much of the same functionality (without bridging it first, of course, is that what they mean?). I have found a few posts and a bit of info here and there, but nothing that convincing. Does anyone have any knowledge or insight?

My app specifically is using `NSDecimalNumber` for currency and formatting, so rounding and formatting are a high priority.

Comment: As far as I can see, `NumberFormatter(style: .decimal)` does not compile, moreover, `NumberFormatter()` does not create an optional. – Is that your real code, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: `extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(style: NumberFormatter.Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = style
    }
    func string(from decimal: Decimal) -> String? {
        return string(from: decimal as NSNumber)
    }
}`

Comment: Yeah, that's my real code and it compiles fine. I'm on Xcode 8.1, has this changed in 8.2 or something?

Comment: Doesn't compile for me in Xcode 8.1, because there's no such initializer.

Comment: sorry, that was a simple NSNumberFormatter extension we have, the code has been updated

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I asked my question on the swift-users board and got a wonderful answer, check it out here: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20161219/004220.html

Text version of the response:

*Swift 3 introduced the Decimal class, which at first I thought was supposed to 'replace' NSDecimalNumber in Swift, like Error is the new NSError, etc.  However, upon further investigation, it's not clear to me that this is actually the case. It appears that Swift 3's Decimal is more just an NSDecimal, but with some bridging so it can use NSDecimalNumber's methods when needed. What I'm wondering is, should I be replacing NSDecimalNumber in my app with Decimal? Is Decimal the successor to NSDecimalNumber in Swift?*

`Decimal` is actually a struct, not a class, and in fact it's just the Swift name for the `NSDecimal` struct in Objective-C. In Swift, functions like `NSDecimalAdd` are exposed as operators on `Decimal` and are used to satisfy the requirements of various numeric protocols like `SignedNumber`.

The end result is that `Decimal` is a lot like `Int` or `Double`—it's a value type which can be conveniently used to do all sorts of math. `NSDecimalNumber`, then, is equivalent to `NSNumber`.

*Since my app is doing a lot of formatting, it would require much casting between Decimal and NSDecimalNumber, or adding of extensions to use, so I don't think it would be natural/convenient without many extensions. Is Swift planning to improve Decimal to be more usable with NumberFormatter, or other object-oriented number APIs? Hopefully I have given enough information to answer my question.*

Objective-C APIs which use `NSDecimalNumber` should be bridged to `Decimal`, just as `NSString` is bridged to `String`. That bridging may not work for category methods, though; you could expose those to Swift by writing an extension on `Decimal` which casts `self` to `NSDecimalNumber` and then calls through to your Objective-C methods.

Similarly, you should be able to use `Decimal` with `NumberFormatter` by casting to `NSDecimalNumber`, just as you would cast `Int` or `Double` to `NSNumber` to use them with `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: what is the advantage of using it over `Double` type?

Comment: @brahimm You should never use Double/Float to represent Currency. You can read a nice explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: @Caio I have the same concern, but I'm now also concerned that Swift's `Decimal` doesn't address this :/