# Why subtracting NSDecimalNumbers do not work - Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsdecimalnumber

Why am I getting `0` when subtracting `5.0` from `650.50` using the `subtracting()` method?

in the following code, adding, multiplying and dividing work fine, but why subtracting doesn't? What am I doing wrong?

See code in IBM's sandbox:
http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59b1387696a0602d6cb19201

```
import Foundation

let num1:NSDecimalNumber = 650.50
let num2:NSDecimalNumber = 5.0 

let result = num1.adding(num2)
let result2 = num1.subtracting(num2)
let result3 = num1.multiplying(by: num2)
let result4 = num1.dividing(by: num2)

print("Addition: \(result)") // Addition: 655.5
// Why am I getting 0 here and not 645.5?
print("Subtraction: \(result2)") //Subtraction: 0
print("Multiplication: \(result3)") //Multiplication: 3252.5
print("Division: \(result4)") //Division: 130.1
```

Apples Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber

Comment: I got " 645.5" in XCode Swift Playground. Could be an issue on the IBM part (well let's say not iOS/macOS Swift part).

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Thank your for checking (I'm away from my computer at the moment).

Comment: Try with `result2.doubleValue`

Comment: `result2.doubleValue` works, but according to the documentation it should return an NSDecimalNumber without you having to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because of a specificity of the IBM sandbox related to NSDecimalNumber (indeed many parts of Foundation are still not entirely available on Linux).

Anyway, whatever the bug is, a solution is to use the Swift counterpart to `NSDecimalNumber` which is `Decimal.`

Despite the fact that this is supposed to be only a wrapper around NSDecimalNumber, it gives the correct result, even on the IBM platform.

Note that this wrapper doesn't use the NSDecimalNumber methods, it uses Swift operators such as `+` or `*`.

```
import Foundation

let num1: Decimal = 650.50
let num2: Decimal = 5.0

let result = num1 + num2
let result2 = num1 - num2
let result3 = num1 * num2
let result4 = num1 / num2

print("Addition: \(result)")
print("Subtraction: \(result2)")
print("Multiplication: \(result3)")
print("Division: \(result4)")
```

Gives:

> Addition: 655.5
>   Subtraction: 645.5
>   Multiplication: 3252.5
>   Division: 130.1

Comment: Quick question, is `Decimal` considered the same as `NSDecimalNumber`? In other words, is `Decimal` recommended currency? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Decimal` is supposed to be the same type as `NSDecimalNumber` but converted to Swift. It is truly intended for money calculations (decadic, high precision arithmetic). However, there are some methods missing compared to `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @fs_tigre The documentation states that the two are bridged, so I'd say that yes, Decimal is supposed to have the same behavior.

Comment: Cool, `Decimal` may be my best choice since you can use the native Swift operators (+, - etc.). I will look into what methods will I be missing by using `Decimal`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe that Decimal actually corresponds to NSDecimal.  NSDecimalNumber is a wrapper around NSDecimal.  In either case, it's the preferred way of dealing with currency.  See this answer for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264395/3203487

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't wrong and works correctly in Xcode/macOS. However, IBM's Swift sandbox uses Linux, and the implementation of `Foundation` on Linux has [issues](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Issues.md). In the [Status](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/84ee193f9181838a366fe5f5e02d6345c7338c3a/Docs/Status.md) page of the repo, `NSDecimalNumber` is marked as "Unimplemented". Therefore, it may have some problems. Use classes from the standard library instead.