# How to convert Decimal to String with two digits after separator?

Tags: ios, swift, string, decimal, number-formatting

This is what I do now:

```
extension Decimal {
    var formattedAmount: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter.string(from: self) //mismatch type
    }
}
```

but I cannot create `NSNumber` from `Decimal`.

Comment: `string(for: self)` – compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999137/1187415

Comment: Or `string(from: self as NSDecimalNumber)` – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41148782/1187415

Comment: @MartinR I didn't noticed the existence of `string(for: self)` is it documented?, I was aiming to add an answer as mentioned in your second comment, it's late for now :)

Comment: It is documented, as a method of the "abstract" superclass [`Formatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter) of `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
extension Decimal {
    var formattedAmount: String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter.string(from: self as NSDecimalNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use generatesDecimalNumbers property when converting from Decimal to String. Use it in case of String to Decimal

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
formatter.string(from: ...) // requires a NSNumber
```

You can either do this:

```
formatter.string(for: self) // which takes Any as argument
```

Or:

```
string(from: self as NSDecimalNumber) // cast self to NSDecimalNumber
```

Comment: The syntax did *not* change between Swift 3 and Swift 4.